# It takes double click to show click effect on imageButton through onClick()

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-imagebutton

I want click effect when image is clicked but from my code whenever i click image for the first time nothing happen however when i click for second time it shows orange colour effect that image was clicked . Below is my code ,I know this might  not be the correct way to do this . But i want to know why this is happening

image.xml

```
 <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
               android:background="@drawable/fear_96"
                android:onClick="see"
                android:id="@+id/abulation"
                />
```

below is onclick method

```
  public void see(View view) {

    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xf0f47521,   
PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    view.invalidate();
             startActivity(view.getId());
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
  }

  public void startActivity(int id)
  {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,DuwaListView.class);
    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.abulation:
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Abulation");
            break;
        case R.id.dressing:
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Dressing");
        break;
        case R.id.restroom:
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Restroom");
            break;
        default:

Toast.makeText(this,"underconstruction",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;


    }


    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Please help why this code is showing such behaviour

Comment: Simply use _AlphaAnimation_ or _ObjectAnimator_

Comment: My question is why it is showing such behaviour? I know there are other methods to do that. Please read last line of my question before simply down voting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on image for the first it just set the **Touch Listener** on the image.
So instead of adding touch listener to image inside the see function.
Try it with outside this.

```
<ImageView
  style="@style/icon"
  android:background="@drawable/fear_96"
  android:id="@+id/abulation" />

ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.abulation);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xf0f47521, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    view.invalidate();
                    startActivity(view.getId());
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: i have around 45 imageButton and i didnt to want make that much object so i was just trying to do in this way . I was also thinking in that way but it is good to know the real reason behind this . Anyways thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the

```
startActivity(view.getId());
```

above the

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
```

or

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
```

it worked for me.
hope this helps